# Leafletjs get latlng center position of polyline

Tags: leaflet, line, circle

**After drawing a polyline, I would like to draw a circle from the center of this line whose radius encompasses the entire line.**

For polyline's that have more than 2 points I can crudely get the center point like this:

```
// Get middle latLng on polyline
var streetLatLngs = layer.getLatLngs();
var numPoints = streetLatLngs.length;
var middleIndex = Math.round(numPoints / 2);
var centerPoint = streetLatLngs[middleIndex];

var circle = L.circle(centerPoint, 100);
circle.addTo(map);
```

Which produces:

[image: center point]

However as you can see when there are only 2 points, I can't calculate the center latlng, and I can't guarantee that the middleIndex is actually the middle point.

Once I have that I can get the radius with:

`Math.round(streetLatLngs[0].distanceTo(streetLatLngs[numPoints - 1]) / 2);`

which correctly produces the circle raduis:

[image]

Comment: By curiosity, what do you need this circle for?

Comment: I was going to attempt to darken the map and only have the map inside the circles as a lower opacity

Comment: If this is just in the current view, then try using pixel locations to calculate decent radius they translate back to latlng.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calculate the bounding box of the line (using `getBounds()` in Leaflet), put a circle with the center at the center of the bounding box, and the radius chosen as half width or height of the bounding box, whichever is highest.

Comment: Ah how did I miss the getCenter() function of LatLngBounds. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

To be mathematically strict, the middle point of polyline is not placed in the average of LatLng coordinates of starting and ending point (as suggested in the other answers or using `getCenter()` method).

Polyline in Leaflet draws a straight line over a [Mercator projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection), so latitudes are deformed. When working on small scale, like the example on this post, the differences will not be considerable, but it your Polyline goes from Argentina to Russia you can see that the middle point (using LatLng coordinates, i.e., (lat_1/2+lat_2/2, lng_1/2+lng_2/2)) does not lay on the Polyline.

If you want to exactly get the latitude and longitude of the point that lays exactly in the middle of your Polyline, you need to consider the equations that describe Mercator projection. The following lines should do the job:

```
let srcLatRad = srcLat  * (Math.PI / 180);
let dstLatRad = dstLat  * (Math.PI / 180);
let middleLatRad = Math.atan(Math.sinh(Math.log(Math.sqrt(
  (Math.tan(dstLatRad)+1/Math.cos(dstLatRad))*(Math.tan(srcLatRad)+1/Math.cos(srcLatRad))))));
let middleLat = middleLatRad * (180 / Math.PI)
let middleLng = (srcLng + dstLng) / 2;
```